# In my JavaScript server, why does my posted data have braces and quotes around it?

Tags: javascript, rest, curl

I have a simple JavaScript server to process a POST command. But my post data shows up surrounded with braces and quotes. I'm using curl to send this:

`curl --data {title:'Odessey',author:'Homer'} localhost:4444/test/add`

But my server gets the posted data like this:

`{ "{title:'Odessey',author:'Homer'}": '' }`

When I send it back to the client, it shows up with spaces removed and quotes converted:

`{"{title:'Odessey',author:'Homer'}":""}`

Curiously, if I put quotes around the string in curl, I get exactly the same thing:

`curl --data "{title:'Odessey',author:'Homer'}" localhost:4444/test/add`

I'm running this on Windows 10. The problem doesn't seem to be with curl, because I wrote another (clumsier) server without using express, and this problem didn't show up. Also, I've tried curl's other options for sending data, like `--data.ascii` and `--data.raw`, but none of them help. So the problem must be with the express server.

Also, I log the req's Content-Type before processing the POST DATA. By default, it prints out `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. At the suggestion of other users, I changed the Content-Type header in the curl statement by saying `curl -H Content-Type:application/json`, but that didn't help. The log statement confirms that it received this header, but then it fails to read the data at all, logging `req.body: {}`.

Here's my server code:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

// taking this block out doesn't help. Without it, I don't get any data.  
app.use(
    express.urlencoded({ extended: true })
);

// Changing this to express.text() doesn't help. Nor does removing it.
app.use(express.json());

app.post('/test/add', (req, res) => {
    let hdr = "Content-Type";
    console.log(hdr, req.header(hdr)); 
    console.log("req.body:", req.body);
    res.send(req.body);
})

var server = app.listen(4444, function() {
    var urlStr = "http://" + host + ':' + port;
    console.log ("Example app listeneing at", urlStr);
})
```

**Note:** I have updated this slightly since I first posted it.

Comment: Why are you sending an object? Why are you not sending JSON?

Comment: In my thinking, I was just sending a string. But since you ask, I changed the curl request to this: `curl --data {"title":"Odessey","author":"Homer"} localhost:4444/test/add` It didn't help.

Comment: Try creating the request in Postman and then open the code tab on the right margin (with the </> icon) and see how Postman generate the curl command for the request

Comment: FWIW this is what Postman generated for me: `curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:4444/test/add' --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --data-raw '{"title":"Odessey","author":"Homer"}'`

Comment: `curl` has a documentation, [`--data`](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html#-d) in itself sends a "form" in particular, which then your server helpfully decodes. As your "form" has a key only, with no value, the value is an empty string. Try `curl --data "{title:'Odessey',author:'Homer'}" --data "Miguel=Munoz" localhost:4444/test/add` and you will see. Otherwise `curl --data "{title:'Odessey',author:'Homer'}" -H "Content-Type: application/octet-stream" localhost:4444/test/add` may avoid your data getting treated as a form.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this by adding the following header:    `-H 'Content-Type: application/json'`. It is receiving it as a `GET` parameter (something like `localhost:4444/test/add?{title:'Odessey',author:'Homer'}`).

Comment: not that in JSON the keys are quoted, and only double quote are valid.

Comment: That didn't work. To even try it, I had to change the header option to this: `-H 'Content-Type:%20application/json'` But that didn't help.

Comment: I have now discovered that curl's -H option requires that I specify a file path, not a header. So I created a file containing `Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8` but that didn't help either.

Comment: Both are wrong, in Windows command-line `'` and `"` are not interchangable, `-H "Content-Type: application/json"` would have been the right guess. @MiguelMunoz if you wanted to send headers from a file, it has a separate syntax with a `@`, https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html#-H

Comment: @tevemadar Thank you for the suggestion. That gave me this: SyntaxError: Unexpected token t in JSON at position 1. I tried it using both {title:'Odessey',author:'Homer'} and {"title":'Odessey',"author":'Homer'} for the POST data.

Comment: @tevemadar I also discovered that the right way to pass the -H argument is like this: `-H Content-Type:application/json`. No quotes, no spaces. When I do this, my server logs the type I specified. But whenever I specify anything, I usually get an empty result: {}

Answer (score 0):

Mario Martín Moreno had a very useful suggestion to add a -H option to my curl command. This was correct, but the form wasn't quite right. @dandavis was correct that only double quotes were valid for the keys. And @tevemader was right that I was using a header file incorrectly. But the crucial detail was that I needed to escape my quote characters with a backslash. So the full curl line looked like this:

`curl --data {\"title\":\"Odessey\",\"author\":\"Homer\"} -H Content-Type:application/json localhost:4444/test/add`

Caveats: Single quotes don't work even on just the values, and even with the backslash to escape them. And I still don't know why I needed to do this here, but not with my earlier server that didn't use express. But at least I know how to use curl to send my data. Thank you to everyone who responded with helpful suggestions.